# Transform XML to XML using XSLT removing leading spaces and zeroes

Tags: xml, xslt

Please help: trying to transform the XML by removing leading **zeroes and spaces**; the below XSLT is not working for me:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" 
exclude-result-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <h1>
            <xsl:variable name="leadingZeroRemoved">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeLeadingZero">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="leadingSpaceRemoved">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeLeadingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$leadingZeroRemoved" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="trailingSpaceRemoved">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeTrailingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$leadingSpaceRemoved" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$trailingSpaceRemoved" />
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="removeLeadingZero">
    <xsl:param name="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="h1" select="$text" />
    <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="starts-with($text,'0')">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeLeadingZero">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                    select="substring-after($text,'0')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>




<xsl:template name="removeLeadingSpace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="h1" select="$text" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($h1,' ')">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeLeadingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($h1,' ')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$h1" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="removeTrailingSpace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="h1" select="$text" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="str:ends-with($h1,' ')">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeTrailingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="str:substringBeforeLast($h1,' ')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$h1" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input and output generated are:

```
$  cat newXMLTEST.FILE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><School>
<Student>
<Id_Numer>0000034</Id_Numer>
<Name>   David</Name>
<Tot_Marks>000000100</Tot_Marks>
<Last_YearTot_Marks>000000000</Last_YearTot_Marks>
<Fee_Paid>000043.01</Fee_Paid>
</Student>
</School>
$  cat ne.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>
<Student>
<Id_Numer>0000034</Id_Numer>
<Name>   David</Name>
<Tot_Marks>000000100</Tot_Marks>
<Last_YearTot_Marks>000000000</Last_YearTot_Marks>
<Fee_Paid>000043.01</Fee_Paid>
</Student>
</School>
```

But what i am looking for is something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>
<Student>
<Id_Numer>34</Id_Numer>
<Name>David</Name>
<Tot_Marks>100</Tot_Marks>
<Last_YearTot_Marks>0</Last_YearTot_Marks>
<Fee_Paid>43.01</Fee_Paid>
</Student>
</School>
```

I am beginner to XSLT and Xpath.I modified some online version of XSLT and trying with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by sating "it is not working"? The template will remove leading spaces if called correctly (although not if there is a newline as the first character for example). Showing some example input and the output you are currently getting (as well as what you would expect) might help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>
<Student>
<Id_Numer>0000034</Id_Numer>
<Name>   David</Name>
<Tot_Marks>000000100</Tot_Marks>
<Last_YearTot_Marks>000000000</Last_YearTot_Marks>
<Fee_Paid>000043.01</Fee_Paid>
</Student>
</School>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Id_Numer | Tot_Marks | Last_YearTot_Marks | Fee_Paid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>
  <Student>
    <Id_Numer>34</Id_Numer>
    <Name>David</Name>
    <Tot_Marks>100</Tot_Marks>
    <Last_YearTot_Marks>0</Last_YearTot_Marks>
    <Fee_Paid>43.01</Fee_Paid>
  </Student>
</School>
```

---

### Added:

To make this more generic, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[number(.)=number(.)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you.. But my input xml tags's are not constant.. I have many input xml.. and i don't have any control ... I am looking for something dynamic .. Can i tweek something on your xslt .. thx !   I mean to say XML is not always the same so it's not always Id_Numer | Tot_Marks | Last_YearTot_Marks | Fee_Paid

Comment: @user3342678 See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Sir. it has helped me.. I was trying to normalize the Xmls and compare the differences using unix diff  so i can find the ones i needed. Another question i have is if we have the corrupt xml if the end tag is missing , in the above example if the </Student> end tag is came in as </> .. would it  be possiblle i can ask the xsl to continue with out throwing exception ? now i am getting expected end tag exception.

Comment: XSLT will process only well-formed XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove space(s) between the elements, add the following instruction at the level of the stylesheet element:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

If you want to remove leading and trailing spaces of `text()` nodes, add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```